# Notebook Initialization

Tags: evaluation, notebooks

I am running Mathematica 10.2. I am having trouble automatically initializing a notebook. I realize that there have been several other questions/answers on this topic, but the advice given there doesn't work for me.

I have several cells in the notebook. The first one contains PrependTo and Needs statements for several packages. I have set the cell's property to Initialization Cell. I have used the Options Inspector to set the InitializationCellEvaluation option for the notebook to True and the InitializationCellWarning option for the notebook to False. {Note, these
values are already set in the Options Inspector, and the Apply button is
disabled.}

When I open the notebook, the initialization cell is not executed. In
particular, the packages have not been evaluated. When I do the initialization by hand, everything works fine.

Is there something extra about package evaluation that I have to take care of when doing automatic initialization? Is there any other magic
I have to perform?

Thanks.

Spencer

Comment: Just to be clear: when you try to evaluate some other cell that is not the initialization cell it stills asks you whether you want to evaluate the initialization cells first, right?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It just executes with a complaint that the functions (defined in the (unevaluated) packages) are not graphical primitives.

Comment: I have stripped down the failing notebook and uploaded it to http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~spencer/dl/bar.nb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that I now know the answer. In addition to setting 
  InitializationCellEvaluation option to True
  InitializationCellWarning option to False
with the notebook selected, you also need to set these same values at
the Global Preference level.

Comment: How do you set the same values at the `Global Preference Level`?

Comment: In the Options Inspector, in the Selection dropdown, choose Global Preferences.

Comment: Sorry but where is the `Options` inspector? Is it under `Cell` or other places?

Comment: Format menu -> Options Inspector ...