# Why InitializationCellWarning is False and still I get warnings?

Tags: initialization, security, notebook-security

I wrote a notebook containing initialization cells:

(1)
notebook's options related to initialization are set to:

```
InitializationCellEvaluation -> True
InitializationCellWarning -> False
```

(2)
the notebook is placed into a trusted directory.

By the way, `TrustByDefault` is `True`.

However, in spite of that, I constantly receive the "`Do you want automatically evaluate all initilization cells in the notebook`" and "`This file contains potentially unsafe content`" warnings.

(Q1)
Why does it happen ?

(Q2)
Here [Notebook Initialization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111378/notebook-initialization/111654#111654) is said (about a quite different situation):

> I believe that I now know the answer. In addition to setting
>   InitializationCellEvaluation option to True InitializationCellWarning
>   option to False with the notebook selected, you also need to set these
>   same values at the Global Preference level.

Admitted that this is pertinent to my case, I can't see, nor in `Options Inspector` > `Global Preferences` neither in `tutorial/NotebookSecurity` an explict indication. (8.0.1.0)

Comment: "In order for the warning not to occur, this option must be set to False both in the notebook being opened and at the global level. This is a security feature to prevent a notebook from silently evaluating cells without the user’s knowledge, unless the user has specifically enabled this by setting the option to False at the global level."[http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InitializationCellWarning.html]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply do

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, {InitializationCellEvaluation -> True,
  InitializationCellWarning -> False}];
```

Now Initialization `Cell`s are evaluated without the warning even when these options are not set at the Notebook level explicitly: actually they are simply [inherited](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72990/280) by `Notebook` from the top level (from the `$FrontEndSession`).

Comment: Thanks:  it works fine !   I wonder why `InitializationCellEvaluation ` and `InitializationCellWarning ` options are not shown by `Options Inspector` ...

Comment: @mitochondrial At least these options are listed in `AbsoluteOptions[$FrontEnd]`: try `FilterRules[
 AbsoluteOptions[$FrontEnd], {InitializationCellEvaluation, 
  InitializationCellWarning}]`.