# How to *safely* enable automatic initialization cell evaluation for one notebook?

Tags: notebooks, initialization, security, notebook-security

I want to configure this *one* notebook (let's call it **X**) so that its initialization cells get automatically evaluated when **X** is first opened<sup>1</sup>.

To this end, I have applied the settings shown below to **X**:

```
InitializationCellEvaluation -> True
InitializationCellWarning -> False
```

Still, I get warned about **X**'s initialization cells when I open it.

I [understand](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13248/2464) that one way to do what I want to do entails disabling a "global security option", like so:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, GlobalInitializationCellWarning -> False]
```

Nevertheless, it seems to me a bit excessive to reduce *Mathematica*'s security *globally* just so that I can enable automatic initialization cell evaluation in *one* notebook.

Therefore, I'm looking for more limited ways to achieve the same thing.

(E.g. some way to invoke Mathematica that disables `GlobalInitializationCellWarning` *just for that session*.)

FWIW, I'm using 10.4.1.0 Linux x86 (64-bit).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> This probably should go without saying: the automatic evaluation of the initialization cells should happen *even if the kernel is not yet running*; IOW, the rule I want followed at this notebook's startup is: "If the kernel is not yet running, start it; then, evaluate all the initialization cells".  If this is not possible at all, then the rest of my post is pretty much moot.</sup>

Comment: I think Karsten comment is the answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115493/5478

Comment: is `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, GlobalInitializationCellWarning -> False]` enough?